# Use Java 8 lambdas to find a pair of objects in a list that meet a certain criteria

Tags: algorithm, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Given a List of objects of type `A` and the method `boolean foo(A other);` what's the best way to use Java 8 lambdas to find any pair of objects, such as `a1.foo(a2) == true`?

Note method `foo` is **symmetric**, meaning that `a1.foo(a2) == a2.foo(a1)` (like the `equals`).

Also, what's the best way if I only need to know any `a1`, and not the pair `(a1, a2)`?

**For example:**

Suppose I have a list of students, and I want to find any student with the same age of some other student in the list.

The method Person.sameAgeAs(Person other) below returns `true`/`false`, and is used to compare their age:

```
for (Person student1 : students) {
    for (Person student2 : students) {
        if (!student1.equals(student2)) { // If not the same student.
            if (student1.sameAgeAs(student2)) { // If they have the same age.
                return student1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I want to do it with lambdas:

```
students.stream()...
```

---

**EDIT:**

If method `foo` were **not** symmetric, then @srborlongan 's answer below would be perfect. Encapsulating it in a `Pair` class and accepting a `predicate`:

```
@NotNull
public static <I> Pair<I, I> findPair(@Nullable List<I> list, @NotNull BiPredicate<I, I> predicate) {
    if (list == null) return emptyPair();

    Optional<Pair<I,I>> item = list.parallelStream()
        .flatMap(item1 ->
            list.stream()
            .filter(item2 -> !item1.equals(item2))
            .filter(item2 -> predicate.test(item1, item2))
            .map(item2 -> new Pair<>(item1, item2))).findFirst();

    return item.orElse(emptyPair());
    }
```

But, as I said, `foo` is symmetric, and the above code is inefficient because: (i) If an answer exists some symmetric pairs may be searched before all the non-symmetric ones; (ii) and if no answer exists, i.e., `student1.sameAgeAs(student2)` never returns `true` this code will search all pairs, including the symmetric ones. To be efficient the code should only check half of the pairs (since `student1.sameAgeAs(student2) == student2.sameAgeAs(student1)`).

My initial `for (Person ...` example was not good, since it also searches all pairs. This is really what should be translated to lambdas to be efficient:

```
@NotNull
public static <I> Pair<I, I> findPair_Symmetric(List<I> list, BiPredicate<I, I> predicate_Symmetric) {
    if (list != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if ((i != j) && predicate_Symmetric.test(list.get(i), list.get(j))) {
                    return new Pair<>(list.get(i), list.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    return emptyPair();
    }
```

Comment: This algorithm is O(n^2), but it could be made into an O(nlogn) if instead of BiPredicate you could have a Compare functional, and use a TreeSet - than you just fill the tree until you find it already contains an equivalent object.  Further, If you could hash the property you're matching - you could use a HashSet and get O(n) performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//symmetric solution
@NotNull
public static <I> Pair<I, I> findPair_Symmetric(List<I> list, BiPredicate<I, I> predicate_Symmetric) {
  if (list != null) {
    // for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
      .mapToObj(
        // for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++)
        i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, list.size())
          // if (predicate_Symmetric.test(list.get(i), list.get(j))
          .filter(j -> predicate_Symmetric.test(list.get(i), list.get(j)))
          // return new Pair<>(list.get(i), list.get(j));
          .mapToObj(j -> new Pair<>(list.get(i), list.get(j)))
      )
      .flatMap(Function.identity())
      .findFirst()
      .orElseGet(() -> emptyPair())
    ;
  }

  return emptyPair();
}

// to get a1 only

students.stream()
  // Scala-ers (and other functional programming people) usually recommend
  // flatMap to solve life's problems.
  // (Except world peace. World peace is hard.)
  .flatMap(
    // for (Person student1 : students)
    student1 -> students.stream()
      // for (Person student2 : students)
      // if (!student1.equals(student2))
      .filter(student2 -> !student1.equals(student2))
      // if (student1.sameAgeAs(student2))
      .filter(student2 -> student1.sameAgeAs(student2))
      // or .filter(student1::sameAgeAs)
  )
  .findFirst()

// to get a1 and a2 (assuming the method makePair(Student, Student) exists)
// (makePair may return an array, a List, a Set, a Map.Entry, etc.)

students.stream()
  // Scala-ers (and other functional programming people) usually recommend
  // flatMap to solve life's problems.
  // (Except world peace. World peace is hard.)
  .flatMap(
    // for (Person student1 : students)
    student1 -> students.stream()
      // for (Person student2 : students)
      // if (!student1.equals(student2))
      .filter(student2 -> !student1.equals(student2))
      // if (student1.sameAgeAs(student2))
      .filter(student2 -> student1.sameAgeAs(student2))
      // or .filter(student1::sameAgeAs)
      .map(student2 -> makePair(student1, student2))
  )
  .findFirst()
```

Comment: If `student1.sameAgeAs(student2)` never returns `true` your code will search all `(item1,item2)` pairs. But you ignored the fact that method `foo` is **symmetric**, so to be efficient you should only check **half** of the pairs (since `student1.sameAgeAs(student2) == student2.sameAgeAs(student1)`).

Comment: Added symmetric solution.

Comment: **A question:** So, if I change the outer stream to `IntStream.range(0, lista.size()).parallel()` it is supposed to run parallel, and may be faster for big lists than my initial `for` loop? Running faster is the whole point of the exercise, since the lambda solution is less readable than the `for` solution.

Comment: The symmetric solution works. Perfect. I would just ask you to edit it to remove the `.filter(j -> i != j)` line from it, since it is not necessary: `IntStream.range(i + 1, lista.size())` already doesn't include j == i.

Comment: @marcg Test first; Java 8 allows us to create parallelizable code by essentially coding streams in a restricted sequential manner, which we can then decorate with .unordered().parallel() calls to test if there are performance gains.